# How to show that $||X-Y_2||_{L^2} \leq ||X-Y_1||_{L^2}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The question is, Let $X$ be an $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ and $F_i$ be two sigma-fields such that $F_1 \subset F_2$. Let $Y_1 = E[X|F_1]$ and $Y_2=E[X|F_2]$. Show that $||X-Y_2||_{L^2} \leq ||X-Y_1||_{L^2}$.

By the definition, $Y_1 = E[X|F_1]$, then

i) $Y_1 \in F_1$ and ii) for all $A \in F_1$, $\int_{A} X dP = \int_{A} Y_1 dP$.

Since, $A \in F_1 \subset F_2, $ and ,  By the definition, $Y_2 = E[X|F_2]$, then

i) $Y_2 \in F_2$ and ii) for all $A \in F_2$, $\int_{A} X dP = \int_{A} Y_2 dP$.

I tried to use this definition to prove the inequality but did not reach to any conclusion. Is the tower property help here to prove this answer and how?

Comment: Note that $Y_1$is $F_1$-measurable, hence $F_2$-measurable , by definition of measurability. Therefore, you can use the stronger result that for any $F$-measurable random variable $Z$ and any random variable $X$, we have $\|X - E[X|F]\|_2 \leq \|X-Z\|_2$ (of course, provided that these quantities exist). Are you aware of this result?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer could you please give the proof of the inequality that you mentioned above?

Comment: Trying to look for a duplicate, but a sketch is as follows : $E[(X-Z)^2] = E[(X-E[X|F] + E[X|F]-Z)^2] = E[(X-E[X|F])^2] + E[(E[X|F]-Z)^2]$ because $E[2(X-E[X|F])(E[X|F]- Z)] =0$, where you use the fact that $Z$ is $F$-measurable.

Comment: @User124356 If $X \in L^2(\Omega, A, P)$, $E(X \mid F)$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $L^2(\Omega, F, P)$. So $E(X \mid F)$ is the closest $L^2$ $F$-measurable function to $X$.